# Errors converting a form to JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Having 2 issues submitting a form as JSON via jQuery .ajax method [fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/9VBEW/4/). Using my current function to get the form data, I get the error 'Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON' and believe it is due to submitting a date from a date picker in the form.

> From json.org : "A value can be a string in double quotes, or a number, or true or false or null, or an object or an array. These structures can be nested."

I can't seem to get the format right either, I need to submit the data like this:

```
{
    "type": "value",
    "identification": {
        "ssn": "value"
    },
    "date_of_birth": "value",
    "name": {
        "first": "value",
        "middle": "value",
        "last": "value"
    },
    "address": {
        "street1": "value",
        "street2": "value",
        "city": "value",
        "state": "value",
        "postal_code": "value",
        "country_code": "value"
    }
}
```

and not sure how to get the nested parent, child and grandchild nesting. Here is my convert to JSON funciton:

```
function ConvertFormToJSON(form) {
    var array = $(form).serializeArray();
    var json = {};

    $.each(array, function(){
    json[this.name] = this.value || '';
});
  return json;
}
```

and here is my attempt at the submission

```
$('#USForm').validate({
    errorLabelContainer: "ul#msgBox",
    wrapper: "li",


    submitHandler: function(form) {

        var form = this;
        var json = ConvertFormToJSON(form);
        $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          url:'http://ec2-54-201-216-39.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/testc/WebService.asmx?op=VerifyIdentityJson',
          crossDomain:true,
          data: json,
          dataType : 'json'
        })
        .always(function(){
          console.log("always:" + json);
        })
        .done(function (response){
          console.log("done:" + json);
        })
        .fail(function(){
         console.log("fail" + json);
        });
        return false;
    },
    rules: {
        //rules
    },
    messages: {
      //messages
});
```

Comment: I don't see a reason why you'd get that error.

Comment: Please create a demo that reproduces the problem, you haven't even loaded the `jQuery.validation` library.

Comment: Sorry man, I updated the fiddle link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter (*form*) returns the `validator` instance for me. The `currentForm` property of it gives you the current `form` element.

For creating the JSON structure I would suggest using identifiers for grouping the form controls, I have used `data-group` attribute in the following demo:

```
<input type="hidden" data-group="address" name="country_code" id="country_code" value="US">
```

Then you can create an object using a loop:

```
// Please do not use a StudlyCase name for a non-Constructor function
function ConvertFormToJSON(form) 
{
    var elems = [].slice.call(form.elements);
    var o = {};
    $.each(elems, function() {
        var $this = $(this), 
            g = $this.data('group');

         // if the current element has data-group attribute
        if (g) {
            // if the object doesn't have `group` property yet
            // create an object so we can set a property to it later
            if ( !o.hasOwnProperty(g) ) {
               o[g] = {};
            } 
            o[g][this.name] = this.value;
        } else {
           // otherwise set a top level property
           o[this.name] = this.value;
        }
    });

    return o;
}
```

Please note that I have manipulated the `rules` property just for passing validation.

http://jsfiddle.net/4nLLM/

Comment: Really awesome man, I have so many questions. Really great and much appreciated, I'd buy you a beer if I could.